# Thor subcommands in different gems

Tags: ruby, thor

I've seen several examples of subcommands in Ruby but haven't found any yet that use Thor, I guess it's possible that it can't be done but I'd be surprised. What I'm trying to do is have a program `foo` that has it's own gem and when installed its commands can be called the usual way, and then I want a separate gem `bar` that registers with `foo`, is maintained in another repository, but gets installed such that I can call it using `foo bar`.

From what I can tell from the Thor documentation in order for `foo` to be aware of `bar` it would need to do this:

```
desc "bar ...", "do bar"
subcommand "bar", Bar
```

But I don't want `foo` to have to know about `bar` and for it to just load it when it's called. I don't really understand how to control how gems are installed so that might be the answer, possibly subcommands need to follow some install rules and the parent command does a generic load of that path. Any chance there's an amazing example out there that I can be pointed at?

Comment: It sounds like what you're after is a plugin model. A core gem with a basic cli, then people can write/install additional gems to extend its functionality. I'm curious about this as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `thor` works. Using `foo` and `bar`, what you would have is a `module foo` with a class `Cli` that inherits from `Thor` ie

```
class Cli < Thor
```

Within your `Cli` class you would define a method `bar`

Something like

```
module foo
  class Cli < Thor
    desc 'bar', 'do stuff'
    def bar 
      # all the rad stuff I do
    end
   end
 end
```

You would then build and install a single gem `foo` which would be available after you `rbenv rehash`. Once available

```
$ foo bar arg1="bang" arg2="boom"
```

will do all of the rad stuff you told it to do.

You can also write your commands in separate files. You might have a `lib` structure as follows:

```
lib
| - foo.rb
| - foo
| | cli
| | - bar_cli.rb
| | - baz_cli.rb
```

In `foo.rb`

```
module Foo
  module Cli
    require_relative 'cli/bar_cli'
    require_relative 'cli/baz_cli'
  end

  class FooCli < Thor
    register(Foo::BarCli, 'bar', 'bar', 'bar commands')
    register(Foo::BazCli, 'baz', 'baz', 'baz commands')
  end
end
```

In `bar_cli.rb`

```
 module Foo
   class BarCli < Thor
     desc 'display', 'Display the bar'
     def display
      # bar display stuff 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I get that's how Thor works, but the question is more to do with how to load Thor subcommands as different installed gems under the same module/namespace. I don't want to have to know how to do everything in the parent.

Comment: Your phrasing is confusing me. Are you trying to write your sub commands in different files? Yes, you can do this. Are you trying to have sub commands load as separate gems? No. You would write separate gems in that case and I could see some namespace headaches if you need them to have the same base command. Amending my answer to reflect writing a command with subcommands in different files.

Comment: I think tasks and Thorfiles is what I'm looking for - eg. http://thehelpcentre.xyz/question/8410840/how-to-make-thor-find-templates-for-system-installed-thor-files.

Comment: I specifically meant gems, not files. An edit was made to the subject line which I've changed back. The concept that I'm seeking is plugins that can be written by other people and are entirely unknown to me at the time of writing the main application.

Comment: I see that you have clarified your original question at the same time. It is much clearer what you are after now. I would suggest that you get it to work in the basic way first, and then attempt to extend from there to meet your additional needs. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. No problem with Thor

Let's have a gem `foo`, providing just a single executable of the same name `foo`, of these contents:

```rb
require 'thor'

class FooCli < Thor
  desc 'hello', 'print a salutation'
  def hello
    puts 'hello'
  end
end

FooCli.start ARGV
```

If I execute it I get output like this

```
Commands:
  foo.rb hello           # print a salutation
  foo.rb help [COMMAND]  # Describe available commands or one specific command
```

There is no problem with adding new subcommands to the executable in code outside of the `foo` gem. Let's have another gem `bar`, providing just a single "library" file of the same name `bar(.rb)`, of these contents:

```rb
require 'thor'

class BarCli < Thor
  desc 'hi', 'print another salutation'
  def hi
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

# Reopen the FooCli class and add the new subcommand
class FooCli < Thor
  desc 'bar', 'subcommand added by the foo-bar plugin'
  subcommand 'bar', BarCli
end
```

The only real issue is how to have `bar` loaded when executing the `foo` command.

## 2. Addressing the issue with code loading

### 2.0 Manual solution

Let's start by loading `bar` manually, using the `-r` option of the `ruby` interpreter:

```
$ ruby -r bar path/to/foo
Commands:
  foo.rb bar             # subcommand added by the foo-bar plugin
  foo.rb hello           # print a salutation
  foo.rb help [COMMAND]  # Describe available commands or one specific command
```

We can see that the code in `bar.rb` took effect. Since it was loaded *before* `foo` itself (that's how the `-r` option works), the `bar` subcommand appears in the command listing *before* the standard `foo` subcommands.

A part of our mission is completed: `foo` knows nothing about `bar`, but `bar` managed to add a subcommand to `foo`. An obvious downside is that the user has to explicitly mention `bar` on each invocation of `foo` (and refer to `foo` by it's full filesystem path, which is also ... not very convenient.)

### 2.1 Plugin system with configuration

The loading of `bar` won't work "magically" out of the box whenever the gem is available, but the users of `foo` will have to specify somewhere (e.g. in a configuration file) that `bar` is to be loaded whenever executing `foo`, and you will add to `foo` a piece of code loading the configuration file and subsequently requiring the plugins specified there.

This has one downside common with the initial solution discussed above: loading of `bar` requires a user intervention, but in this case the intervention is at least required only "once in a lifetime", not on every invocation.

### 2.2 Gem naming magic

If you really want to have `bar` loaded automatically, whenever it's available, but without `foo` having to know (specifically) about it, you can use RubyGems facilities for inspecting installed gems in combination with a naming convention. The `bar` gem won't be called `bar`, but `foo-bar`, the new name signifying that it's an extension of `foo`, and the `foo` executable will contain an additional piece of code looking for all gems whose name starts with `foo-` and loading them:

```rb
Gem::Specification
  .select {|gemspec| gemspec.name =~ /^foo-/ }
  .collect(&:name)
  .uniq # multiple versions of a single gem may be installed at once
  .each {|name| require name }
```

This solution, too, has a downside: if your gem is intended for general use and released at Rubygems, you have no control over people creating gems with names starting with `foo-`. Thus, while trying to automagically load all `foo` plugins, you may load and execute third-party code you have never wanted to. Even worse, if such a problem occurs, the user of `foo`, even if he is fortunate enough to understand what's going on, has no other way to prevent loading the offending `foo-*` gem but uninstalling it.

Comment: hi someone replied to one of my questions about pygame.midi with with a piece of code but I failing to pass parameters in order to initialize or launch it, please I would appreciate your input here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67642570/pygame-midi-how-to-detect-simultaneous-inputs-from-a-synthesizer/67662659#67662659