# Clear a lineEdit inputMask in python

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit

How can I clear a mask in python? I'm using `setInputMask` to insert a mask in a `qLineEdit` but after a period i want to clear the `lineEdit` (remove the mask). I tried to use `clearMask`, `clear`, and `setText("")` but none worked.

The MVCE:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QLineEdit,QWidget,QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator,QDoubleValidator,QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class lineEditDemo(QWidget):
        def __init__(self,parent=None):
                super().__init__(parent)

                e3 = QLineEdit()
                e3.setInputMask("+99_9999_999999")
                e3.clearMask()
                e3.clear()
                e3.setText("")
                
                flo = QFormLayout()
                flo.addRow("Input Mask",e3)
                self.setLayout(flo)
                self.setWindowTitle("QLineEdit Example")

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        win = lineEditDemo()
        win.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What method should I use to clear the `lineEdit` mask since `clearMask` and others don't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass an empty string to [`setInputMask()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) As the docs point out:

> If no mask is set, inputMask() returns an empty string.

```py
e3.setInputMask("")
```

Note: `clearMask()` clears another type of mask: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask

Answer (score 2):

Just use an empty string:

```
setInputMask('')
```

I strongly suggest you to read the documentation instead of trying random things, as it's clear that [`clearMask()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#clearMask) has absolutely nothing to do with it, while [`inputMask`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) clearly states:

> Unset the mask and return to normal QLineEdit operation by passing an empty string ("").

Comment: someone replied to one of my questions about pygame.midi with with a piece of code but I failing to pass parameters in order to initialize or launch it, please I would appreciate your input here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67642570/pygame-midi-how-to-detect-simultaneous-inputs-from-a-synthesizer/67662659#67662659